# Pivot columns with aggregated function and calculate total of aggregated value in last column

Tags: sql-server

Hi my source data is like,

```
date    E1  E2  E3  Total
05-25-15    4   2   2   8
05-26-15    5   0   4   9
05-27-15    5   0   4   9
05-28-15    0   4   8   12
05-29-15    0   5   2   7
05-30-15    0   8   4   12
```

and i want result like,

```
Error type  Total   Cumulative  Contribution%
E1          190         190       190/490
E2          100         290       290/490
E3          80          370       370/490
E4          70          440       440/490
```

and result something like,

Error type   05-25-15   05-26-15   Total            Contribution%
    E1         4            5        9                9/17
    E2         2            0        2                2/17
    E3         2            4        6                6/17

Comment: hey Tim ,i am really new in sql , I want result like error 1,2,3 columns as in row and the total sum column in second column. like in second table.

Comment: the number of column is 46 error type, the result like in col1 all 46 error and second col2 total sum of each error in front of them.

Comment: Google "how to do a running total in sql server" and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
select a.error 'Error Type',a.Total,sum(b.Total) 'Cumulative',convert(varchar(25),a.Total)+'/'+convert(varchar(25),sum(a.total) over()) from(
select 1 as id, 'E1' as Error ,sum(E1) as total
from tablename
Union all
select 2 as id, 'E2' as Error ,sum(E2) as total
from tablename
Union all
select 3 as id, 'E3' as Error ,sum(E3) as total
from tablename
Union all
select 4 as id, 'E4' as Error ,sum(E4) as total
from tablename)a
join (select 1 as id, 'E1' as Error ,sum(E1) as total
from tablename
Union all
select 2 as id, 'E2' as Error ,sum(E2) as total
from tablename
Union all
select 3 as id, 'E3' as Error ,sum(E3) as total
from tablename
Union all
select 4 as id, 'E4' as Error ,sum(E4) as total
from tablename)b on b.id<=a.id
```

Comment: great !!! Thanks Mukesh, it helps me to solved my problem.

Comment: How i calculate sum of Total in last row

Comment: It is add manual in ui.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative way, this is how you can do this using unpivot, CTEs and rollup:

```
;with CTE as (SELECT ErrorType, sum(Value) as Value
FROM (SELECT E1, E2, E3 FROM table1) p
UNPIVOT (Value FOR ErrorType IN (E1, E2, E3)
)AS u group by ErrorType)

select ErrorType, 
       Value as Total, sum(Value) over(order by ErrorType asc) As Cumulative,
       convert(varchar, sum(Value) over(order by ErrorType asc)) 
           + '/' + convert(varchar, sum(Value) over()) As Contribution
from CTE
```

The first CTE transforms the columns into rows + sums them, the second one calculates the values for the rows and the final select is there just for the rollup (=total) row.

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43b56d/10).

Edit: Removed the total row completely

Comment: @DatabasePirate This works just fine with zeros and even NULLs, as long as you have at least one non-null value, see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/771b5/1 But why would you store NULLs to a count -column anyway, that's just asking for trouble

Comment: The last row Total that i don't want in first row, bcs i am sorting Total by DESC order then it comes first. or how i remove this column from my result ,i will manage it in UI

Comment: @DatabasePirate Without the total row the SQL is lot more simpler and you can remove the second CTE completely. I edited the answer + SQL Fiddle to have a version without total row.

Comment: @DatabasePirate If you want to sort by total, this is how it should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71464/2

Comment: Yess !!! This is what i am looking for, Now everything is perfect. Thanks James.

Comment: Hey James, how to add all date as column name in the same result before total i want 05-25-15,05-26-15.... date columns and their total by date. Now we take all the dates total.

Comment: @DatabasePirate Assuming the number of dates / columns isn't fixed, it gets quite messy and you'll have to use dynamic sql to create a pivot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: how can i add date as column name in our case. I am not able to change our query. i think i m missing something. can you help me by changing our answered query or on SQL Fiddle.